# Посчитать количество слов в каждом предложении текста

Tags: c

Необходимо посчитать количество слов в каждом предложении используя флаговую переменную

```
while( (c = getchar()) !=EOF)
    {

    if(c=='.'||c=='!'||c=='?')
    {
    state=OUT;
    }
    else if(c == ' ' || c == '\t')
    {
    state=IN;
    count++;
printf("%d\n",count);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c=='.' || c=='!' || c=='?' || c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') /*if(ispunct(c) || isspace(c) || iscntrl(c))*/
        {
            if(state==IN)
                count++;
            state=OUT;
        }
        else if(isalpha(c)) /*else if(isalumn(c))*/
        {
            state=IN;
        }
    }
```